# Add Additional Information In Tooltip R Highcharts

Tags: javascript, r, highcharts, r-highcharter

I have some data that I would like to graph using highcharts. When I hover over a given point, I would like the tooltip to also include the column "type". Here is my current reproducible example.

```
library(highcharts)
dat = data.frame(first = rnorm(10), second = rnorm(10), type = rep(c("AAPL", "MSFT"),5))

highchart()%>%
            hc_xAxis(categories = dat$Open_Date)%>%
            hc_add_series(name = "first", data = dat$first, type = "column")%>%
            hc_add_series(name = "second", data = dat$second, type = "line")
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you pass in `dat` as `data` in your `hc_add_series` function, you can access other columns in the `tooltip` argument, like `type`:

```
library(highcharter)

dat = data.frame(first = rnorm(10), second = rnorm(10), type = rep(c("AAPL", "MSFT"),5))

highchart()%>%
  #hc_xAxis(categories = dat$Open_Date)%>%
  hc_add_series(name = "first", data = dat, hcaes(y = first), type = "column", 
                tooltip = list(pointFormat = "{point.type}: {point.first}"))%>%
  hc_add_series(name = "second", data = dat, hcaes(y = second), type = "line",
                tooltip = list(pointFormat = "{point.type}: {point.second}"))
```

[image: highcharter with custom tooltip]