# How to add additional information to tooltip in Highcharts in R?

Tags: r, highcharts, tooltip

I have a plot in highcharts in R. In the tooltip, I want to add information which is not a part of the axes to the tooltip.
For eg, i am plotting the 'population of a city' against 'pollution level'. For this, in the tool tip, I have added the population and the pollution level figs. But I also want to add the city name to the tooltip. How do i do this? Any help in this regardwould be appreciated.
Regards
KK

Comment: Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60044393/add-additional-information-in-tooltip-r-highcharts helps to answer your question

Comment: Can you share your data and the code you are using to generate the chart?

Answer (score 0):

I think you would be able to do this using the tooltip.formatter from the highcharts js API:
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.formatter

You can see a handy article on how to do it here:
https://www.highcharts.com/blog/tutorials/working-with-highcharts-javascript-syntax-in-r/?fbclid=IwAR3UzztbrY4rdCbOw1W7DmSq4mWJswJZxIw-xOqGbjIRExj-gsuVEO2zM00